# How can I change the SQL select to a delete using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a select string as follows:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Table1 a 
JOIN Table2 cb ON a.LookupId = cb.CBLookupId 
JOIN Table3 m ON m.Id = cb.Id
```

I want to change it to the following delete

```
DELETE Table1 
FROM Table1 a 
JOIN Table2 cb ON a.LookupId = cb.CBLookupId 
JOIN Table3 m ON m.Id = cb.Id
```

How can I do some manipulation of the `select` to form the `delete`?

I have about 50 of these statements, and they all have different aliases so it will need to work for any `select`.

Comment: In general you would use something like the [TSqlParser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-150) to allow your application to _grok in fullness_ the original query and generate an appropriate `delete` statement, if any.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Will they always be DELETEing from Table1? DELETE with a JOIN syntax varies from vendor to vendor; you should tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN and IN as follows:

```
delete from Table1 a
WHERE a.LookupId in ( SELECT  cb.CBLookupId FROM Table2 cb 
join Table3 m on m.Id = cb.Id)
```